# How to conditionally bind a deep dependency without relying on global configuration?

Tags: ninject

I have something similar to the following:

```
interface IOuter { ... }
interface IInner { ... }

class Outer : IOuter {
    public Outer(IInner inner) { ... }
}

class InnerA : IInner { ... }
class InnerB : IInner { ... }
```

I need to inject either `InnerA` or `InnerB` into `Outer`'s constructor based on an option passed on the command-line.

According to my investigation I have two options:

1. Use conditional binding: `Bind<IInner>().To<InnerA>().When(_ => option == "useA")`,
   and a similar binding for `InnerB`.
2. Use metadata: Bind with `Bind<IInner>().To<InnerA>().WithMetadata("option", "useA")` and resolve with `kernel.Get<IOuter>(metadata => metadata.Has("option") && metadata.Get<string>("option") == option)`

Method #1 works, but I'm putting my bindings in a module that shouldn't have access to the command-line `option` as a global variable. Ideally the module should rely only on contextual information passed down during resolution.

Which leaves me with method #2, but it doesn't work because apparently the metadata applies to resolving the current interface only, i.e. `IOuter` in my case. It doesn't apply when trying to resolve dependencies of `Outer`, i.e. `IInner`, so I'm getting an error from Ninject that it cannot activate `IOuter` (No matching bindings are available).

A third option would be to use `kernel.Get<IOuter>(new ConstructorArgument("inner", ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<IInner>(metadata => ...)))`, but it's too manual and verbose. Also it becomes unwieldy if there are multiple dependencies in the chain that require similar logic.

Is there a way to conditionally bind a dependency (that maybe a few levels deep in the dependency chain) based on metadata passed when resolving the root object, without relying on accessing global configuration/options?

Comment: What's the problem with access global / thread local config? With dependency injection, you won't need to pass it through all the layers. Also, when changing from global to thread local configuration, you only need to change how you put it on the request, but not the implementation which is config dependent itself.

Comment: I think for me it's a matter of style. I prefer that a module shouldn't need to reach out for global state to make a decision. Ideally, all information needed to make a decision should be wrapped in some context object that gets passed down the resolution chain.

Answer (score 0):

> > I need to inject either InnerA or InnerB into Outer's constructor based on an option passed on the command-line.

In other words, the selected component will not change during the application's lifetime.

Just do this:

```cs
if (commandLineArg) {
    Bind<IInner>().To<InnerA>();
} else {
    Bind<IInner>().To<InnerB>();
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to conditional binding using `.When()`. I'm trying to avoid making my module aware of global application state, such as command-line args.

Comment: @khaledh, and where exactly is that `option` of yours coming from? Only use `When` when things change during runtime.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid any conditional binding based on global state. Right now there's a single value for the option at the application level, but probably soon I will have to change my design to run multiple threads, each having its own option. So eventually I will have multiple instances of the outer object, each will have to have a different inner object implementation, ideally based on an option that I can pass when resolving the outer object.